# jQuery Dialog theme not being applied

Tags: jquery, dialog, themes

I'm using jquery-1.4.2.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js.  According to Firebug, both minimized scripts have been loaded. They both appear in the dropdown list on Firebug's Scripts tab.

The dialog is launching, but there's no background and so the text below it shows through, and there's no "window" stuff at all, no titlebar, no X button.  Just the floating/draggable text with a -close- link at the top left corner.

I was under the impression from reading these pages

```
 http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/
 http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/
```

that the UI theme-driven appearance would be automatically applied to the dialog when it was invoked using this barebones call:

```
 $('#dialog').dialog()
```

I would be grateful for suggestions on how to troubleshoot this. Thanks

Comment: Have you made sure the images path in the UI CSS file is pointing to the right place?

Comment: @Tejs, that could very well be it.  The two jquery js files are in the root of my website; and I have a /css folder and a /themes folder off the root. Should the /css and /themes path be relative to the application that is using jquery or relative to the location of the jquery js files?

Comment: The jquery js files care nothing about the location of the theme.  So when you reference the css theme file you just need to make sure it is relative to the html file that links to the css file.  So it sounds like it might look like <link href="themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you include the link to the jQuery ui theme

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```